# Keep leading zero in rccp int

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a function via Rcpp that reverses an integer

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//' Reverse an integer
//'
//' @param x A single integer.
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int reverse_integer(int x) {
  int reverse = 0;
  while(x != 0){
    int remainder = x%10;
    reverse = reverse*10 + remainder;
    x/=10;
  }
  return reverse;
}
```

This works fine for numbers without leading or trailing zeroes

`reverse_integer(123) == 321`

However, when there are zeroes, they will get stripped, i.e.,

`reverse_integer(100) == 1`

How can I best modify this function so I can still operate on it as an integer, but without losing zeroes?

Comment: I presume you started with a string? Just pad the result back up to the original length with `0`s

Comment: No, the input is passed as a numeric value from R

Comment: Then the zeros are gone, nothing you can do about it

Comment: then the 0's are always there but c++ doesn't show them, since 001 is different than 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a string.  001 is not a different integer than 1 in any programming language.  Here's how:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//' Reverse an integer
//'
//' @param x A single integer.
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string reverse_integer(int x) {
  int reverse = 0;
  int ndigits = 0;
  while(x != 0){
    int remainder = x%10;
    reverse = reverse*10 + remainder;
    x/=10;
    ndigits++;
  }
  std::string output(ndigits, '\0');
  char * outputp = &output[0];
  std::string fmt_string = "%0" + std::to_string(ndigits) + "d";
  sprintf(outputp, fmt_string.c_str(), reverse);
  return output;
}
```

Example:

```
reverse_integer(103400)
[1] "004301"
```

Comment: Thought about posting an answer like this... why not just use `std::to_string()` and `std::reverse()`?

Comment: You're right that would be simpler, this was just the first thing that came to mind by trying to extend the poster's code.  It's possible he has a more complicated use case.

Answer (score 3):

By default the number formatter will not print any leading zeroes.

You will need to return a string instead of an int if you want to preserve leading zeroes. You change your function to count the number of trailing zeroes in the input, and prepend them to the returned string.

Comment: Can you give an example of how that would look?

Comment: Can you  using character casting . Int --> character --> reverse-->int. Benchmarking will be horrible